# Connect Facebook Pixel to BigCommerce Cookie Consent Form

Tags: facebook, cookies, pixel, bigcommerce, facebook-pixel

I wonder if someone may be able to help.

Recently, we realised we had to get consent for using the Facebook pixel on our site. I have looked at the developer information on Facebook on how to do this, and I can stop the pixel from sending data to Facebook...

What I need help with is allowing the data to be sent if the visitor accepts the cookies in the BigCommerce cookie bar (say for either the analytics or Targeting; Advertising category) ... the code I have so far in script manager to stop sending the data is this (to note I removed our FB pixel ID and replaced with 0's for this example) I tried to connect it to the BigCommerce cookie banner but failed (I was trying to use tag manager but this failed also):

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
{if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('consent', 'revoke');
fbq('init', '000000000000000');
fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

As you can see I added the fbq('consent', 'revoke'); to the code

More info from Facebook here regarding the codes to use: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/implementation/gdpr/

Thank you for any help you can offer with this  our site is https://www.wolftucker.co.uk

Answer (score 1):

The BigCommerce consent banner sets a cookie (bc_consent) with details on what the user has consented to. You can use that to decide if you need to do the revoke command.

Alternatively you can add your code using the script manager and set the script category to "Targeting; Advertising". This will remove the script if consent is not given.